Pick Video from camera in Android Tablet Using Flutter

i am using image_picker for pick video from camera.
Its working on mobile.
while on android tablet.
when i create a video from and pick in app. the file size is 0.
image path is printing in local cache but when i save this video the video save as a file in 0 Byte.
Code Sample  final result = await picker.pickVideo(source: image_picker.ImageSource.camera);
Uint8List datList=await result.readAsBytes(); log("file length ${datList.length}"); print 0  if i print result.path
the result print  /storage/emulated/0/Movies/123 (2).mp4 to content://media/external_primary/video/media/1000000226  while i am saving this file the file save as 0 byte.


Can you please update your question with your current reproducible code

in the code you shared you don't save anything. please show where you are saving the fule
